# Cannot update UI with Invoke() and BeginInvoke() in C#

Tags: invoke, begininvoke

My main process:

```
public void quoteStartReceive()
{
    Thread thdWrite = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoParseGUIDisplay));
    thdWrite.IsBackground = true;
    thdWrite.Start();
}
```

My thread function:

```
void DoParseGUIDisplay()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        if (myQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            string strOut = myQueue.Dequeue().ToString();
            Tick tick = new Tick(strOut);
            if (tick.m_last != "")
            {
                string msg = "Update Text";

                if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethosInvoker)delegate () {this.textBox1.Text = msg; };
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox1.Text = msg;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No matter I tried to use Invoke() or BeginInvoke(), I cannot update the text in textBox1.
I also tried another way:

```
public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string text);
```

It still cannot help me to update my textBox1.

Help me to find out what stuff I missed. Thanks.

Comment: I found that every time the m_last was updated, the property textBox1.InvokeRequired was true.
After finishing this process, "this.textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethosInvoker)delegate () {this.textBox1.Text = msg; };", the InvokeRequired propery was still true.

So, it cannot go to "else" condition to update my textBox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put an argument before the thread:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

and it should be put after the m_last was updated.

Comment: I tried this way, and it works!!
My textBox1 was updated successfully.